# Share data between widgets and wizard pages

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a set of QWizardPage classes within a QWizard. Separate to this I have a login dialog that takes information and reads from a database. This database information is then stored within a struct I have created.

I want to avoid tight-coupling and global data (and correspondingly Singletons) if I can as I want to try and carry out things in the best way.

Now firstly I currently create the wizard during the initialisation of the application and use a signal/slot to sent the struct to the wizard. This of course means that the wizard has to exist when I create the login form. The other way I suppose is to add a public function to the wizard or update the constructor. But that then means I need to pass the data along into the wizard pages as I create them. Is there a better way to do that, maybe along the lines of the associated part to this question:

The other thing is that I read information from the database at certain stages during the wizard. If you use `registerField()` it seems a nice way to do this but the information I have read from the database is not stored in a widget so I cannot see how to access this data from other pages. Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this but what I dound was that i can create properties in my code and then use `registerField` against those. The example here is very simple but by doing this I can register against anything I needed. I think if you start having more complicated properties that aren't the "normal" types then it might well get a bit more complicated.

```
Q_PROPERTY(int settingID READ getSettingID)

public:
    int getSettingID() const;
```

Then in the code:

```
registerField("test_setting", this, "settingID");

int TestSettingsWizardPage::getSettingID() const
{ 
    // Return the value here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be a good idea to separate GUI from business logic of your application.
You can add a controller class which will process requests to the database and then update the GUI.